# How to force OneDrive to synchronize?

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

I have a new clean installation of Windows 10.

After logging in using my Microsoft account, my OneDrive folder (ie the OneDrive folder in my Users folder) shows:

[image]

But right-clicking the OneDrive icon and selecting View online shows:

[image]

The latter is the correct one and is what I see from another PC's OneDrive folder signed on to the same acocunt.

Obviously there is something wrong with the synchronization.  How do I fix it or how do I force a synchronization?

I suspect the problem came about because I saved a file to the Asus folder with the exact same name that already existed in that Asus folder. The error message complained and asked me to delete it. That's what I did, but the red x refused to go away, and the OneDrive folder won't show the correct content.

At this point, I am not interested in syncing any folders on my PC, other than the OneDrive folder.

Comment: What have you attempted to resolve this? You say "clean install". Have all  updates been installed? Have you checked out [Fix OneDrive sync problems](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-OneDrive-sync-problems-83ab0d8a-8400-45b0-8dcf-dc8aa8a6bcf8#win10)?

Comment: I have let the new computer sit there for 36 hours. It spent many hours downloading stuff and upgrading to 1607. According to your link, I should be having the previous personal sync client as the balloon text says "1 files weren't uploaded to OneDrive". I am not aware there is a newer version or that I have an outdated version. With Windows 10, I couldn't find a way to show a list of updates. I have rebooted many times and leaving it alone to see if it could sync, but nothing happened.

Comment: You have connected your local account to a the same Microsoft Account as the OneDrive account your trying to sync to?

Comment: I ignored the previous version's instructions and did the reset according to the current version troubleshooting steps and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solution:

> onedrive.exe /reset

onedrive.exe is located in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\`.

Comment: This works but you may have to try it a couple of times :+1

Comment: i want only a folder to get synced from the cloud. I don't want to load all the files. It will last very long. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

To resolve the issue you can try these solutions:

**Solution 1) Disable Files on demand option**

Go to Options => Files on demand => unselect Save space and download files as you use them

[image]

In my situation it was caused the issues with onedrive synchronization by this option.

**Solution 2) When you have Files-on-demand grayed out and you can disable GPO Policy:**

Disable the option in GPO policy:

[image]

**Solution 3) When you have Files-on-demand grayed out and you cannot disable GPO Policy:**

This allow you to sync main directory and sub directories:

[image]

You can try to Disable in the registry (but it might be overwritten in future by GPO update.

set: `FilesOnDemandEnabled` to `0` in this branch:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I have tried this to commands:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /shutdown
start %localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background
```

Inspired from this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/981039/can-you-force-a-single-folder-file-to-sync-with-onedrive).

If you need to reset/update OneDrive, I have check this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_drive-mso_win10-mso_365hp/onedrive-status-symbol-does-not-update-on-folder/e329312d-9ae5-4d3b-a9f2-c51fd7859d28):

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset
```