# Add a specific folder to OneDrive, outside of "My Documents"

Tags: windows, sync, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I know the following dialog box in the OneDrive settings.

But how can I add an arbitrary folder to OneDrive sync, which is outside of "My Documents", "My Music", "My Pictures", and more generally outside of `C:\Users\MyUser\...`?

Example: **Let's say I want to add the folder `D:\MyData\ABC\SharedFolder` to OneDrive syncing and nothing else, how do I do that?**

[image]

NB:

- related but very unclear answers: [How Do I Make OneDrive Sync Only Specific Folders?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-make-onedrive-sync-only-specific-folders/92f081e6-8ae1-4f9a-98a4-d50799682a19)
- not duplicate, slightly different: [Can you force a single folder/file to sync with OneDrive?](https://superuser.com/questions/981039/can-you-force-a-single-folder-file-to-sync-with-onedrive)